# How to call a method from shared library using Active Choice Parameter script in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to call a method inside the Active Choice Parameter script in Jenkins declarative pipeline by importing the object from src/com/foo. Build runs successfully with out errors but the build parameters are not updated.

Here's my Jenkinsfile. project parameters works fine with the call to `d.getProjects()` but the CascadeChoiceParameter does not execute `getDatabases(project)` and falls back to fallbackScript. Is there a way I can use the methods in the ChoiceParameter/CascadeChoiceParameter?

```
@Library('shared-library') _

def d = new com.foo.loadConfig()

node {
properties
    ([
        parameters
        ([
            choice(choices: d.getProjects(),description: 'Project List',name: 'project'),
            [
                $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
                choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                filterLength: 1, 
                name: 'database', 
                referencedParameters: 'project', 
                script: 
                [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                    fallbackScript: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: true, 
                        script: 'return ["db"]'
                        ], 
                    script: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: true,
                        script:  
                        '''
                        if (project.equals("Dummy")){
                            return ["db"]
                        } else {
                            def result = getDatabases(project)
                            return result
                        }
                        '''
                        ]
                ]
            ]
        ])
    ])
}

pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
   stage('Build'){
    steps {
       echo 'Building..'
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you also share the error logs from jenkins, when the script falls back to the fallback script. An approach would be to to store the value obtained from the function call in a global variable in the same node block before starting the properties block. Inside the parameter block you could simply pass the value to the parameter. The caveat is that if its a dynamic value you would get values only in runtime and each update would need a pipeline run.
Another approach would be using the extended choice parameter instead of active choice but that would reproach the cascade choice param. You could also go about using a scriptler script for the choice.
You could also check the following format, not sure if this would work, would need a few more details:

```
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', name: 'environmentName',description: 'Deployment Environment', referencedParameters: 'Domain', script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: '''
'return ["error"]'
'''
            ],
            script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: '''
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles;
import org.jenkinsci.lib.configprovider.model.Config;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
@Library('shared-library') _


----------script here
    }   
  }                 
}
return environments
''']
        ]]     
       ])
    ])
```

This is just calling the sharedLib function inside the node block again.

Comment: I see there's an open ticket https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46394?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

Comment: In that case you can use the values/choices params to pass the value into the variable. Outside the properties block :                                                                                               ```   def paramValue = function call(<Params>)                                                                                                             inside the properties block use choices instead of groovy script; choices: paramValue

Comment: I have a workaround with combination of choice parameters and CascadeChoiceParameter using groovy script.

Comment: Can you share, I'd like to check out the approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround with a combination of choice parameters and CascadeChoiceParameter using groovy script. not the prettiest but it works. Ideally I want to move the groovy script to global methods to simplify the pipeline with less code blocks.

```
@Library('shared-library') _

node {
  checkout scm
  properties([
    disableConcurrentBuilds(),
    [$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false],
    parameters([
      booleanParam(description: 'Refresh build parameters', name: 'Refresh'),
      hidden(defaultValue: env.WORKSPACE,name: 'workspace'),
      choice(choices: getOnboardedProjects(),name: 'project'),
      [
        $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        filterLength: 1, 
        name: 'database', 
        referencedParameters: 'project, workspace', 
        script: 
        [
          $class: 'GroovyScript', 
          script: [
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: true,
            script: '''
            import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
            
            fileName = workspace +'/resources/project-mapping.json'

            dbs = getDB(project)
            return dbs

            def getDB(project){
              dbList=[]
              String inputFile = new File(fileName).text
              def InputJSON = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(inputFile)
              def projectConfig = InputJSON.project

              dbList = []

              for (cfg in projectConfig){
                  if (cfg.name == project && !cfg.dbEngine.isEmpty()) {
                      for (rec in cfg.dbEngine){
                          // dbList.add(rec*.key[0])
                          for (i in rec){
                              dbList.add(i.key)
                          }
                      }        
                  } 
              }
              if(dbList.isEmpty()){
                  return dbList.add("Error")
              }
              return dbList
            }
            '''
          ]
        ]
      ]...
      ]
    ])
  ])
}
```